# In IE 11, the "New Tab Page" is causing 404 error in web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

I have a asp.net mvc application. There is a search form and sometime users search with really long string. Since there is a limitation on the query parameter length I did the following.

1. I have made this form as POST method.
2. I have mentioned in the MVC controller to serve this page only for "POST" requests.

This is working perfectly in all the browsers. As usual IE is causing an issue in the following scenario :).

If users are using the search functionality more frequently, IE is adding the result page to the tile of the "New Tab" page under the frequent (Please refer to the [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ7FP.png)). Since the result page is POST only, whenever user clicks the tile, it is giving 404 error and users are annoyed about this.

Is there any meta tag or javascript to tell IE NOT to add this specific page to the favorite tile? Or add the home page to the tile instead of search page?

Note: I know if I allow GET request, 404 error will go away but I don't want to do that. Otherwise, I have to handle this and redirect the page.

Edit: I tried google but I couldn't find any useful information

Comment: this looks like a browser setting so you wont be able to change that. you might be able to do an AJAX call and redirect after the post is made to a proper URL that can handle the result if someone clicks using the frequent visited pages.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! @d3l33t. I think i will go for Daniel's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string p)
{
     var results = SearchResults(p);

     return View("Results", results);
}
```

You can add another action method using verb GET like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search()
{
     return View();
}
```

So this way, if users clicks on the tile they will be redirected to the Search page ready for start typing in your search form.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.  I am thinking of handling this in a generic way instead of handling per occurrence basis. But as of now this is the best I got.